# What does smart merge do in Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, intellij-idea, git-merge

In Android studio there are options at the bottom right corner to handle branches. In Merge option when I merge another remote or local branch, it shows me options like `Force merge` and `smart merge`.

**What exactly they do?**

**When merging with local/remote branches?**

[image: Git branches]

Comment: Note that this applies to all the IntelliJ products (PyCharm, WebStorm, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its similar to Smart Checkout. Android Studio will stash local changes, check out the selected branch, and then unstash the changes. If a conflict occurs during the unstash operation, you will be prompted to merge the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Smart merge executes the following commands:

1. `git stash save "Uncommitted changes before Update at <MM/DD/YY>, <HH:MM>"`
2. `git merge <remote>`
3. `git stash pop` (if merge successful)

If the merge is unsuccessful and you abort or discard changes, you'll need to run `git stash pop` yourself to get back your changes.

You can see the exact commands being executed by examining the Version Control context in Android Studio, in the Console tab:

[image: Log of Git commands in Android Studio]